# elasticsearch search is not working if there is NOT a space

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am getting my feet wet with elasticsearch and php implementation. I have product names like 9 x 4 trucker, 19 x 40 car seat, etc etc

I am searching my index like this

```
$params = [
            'index' => 'myindex',
            'type' => 'products',
            'body' => [
                    'query' => [
                            'match' => [
                                    'name' => '9 x12'
                            ]
                    ],

            ]
    ];
```

so this returns my products that have 9 x 12 in their name. However when I try to search for 9x12 by doing 'name' => '9 x12', nothing gets returned. What am I missing. Thanks

**EDITED**
I used this to populate index

```
PUT /myindex
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have also tried the settings below but they did not work either

```
PUT /myindex
{
"settings":{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "lowercasespaceanalyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},


"mappings": {
 "products" : {
  "properties" : {
    "title" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "lowercasespaceanalyzer", "tokenizer": "lowercase", "search_analyzer":"whitespace", "filter": [
      "lowercase"
    ] }
  }
 }
}
}
```

**UPDATE :: My Current Mapping**

I used the api call to get the current mapping. Not sure if this would help but here it is

```
{
clipboards: {
mappings: {
products: {
properties: {
product: {
properties: {
bottomleft_png: {},
bottomright_png: {},
cost: {},
date_added: {},
date_available: {},
date_modified: {},
description: {},
ean: {},
height: {},
image: {},
isbn: {},
jan: {},
length: {},
length_class_id: {},
location: {},
manufacturer_id: {},
minimum: {},
model: {},
mpn: {},
options: {},
points: {},
price: {},
product_gallery: {},
product_id: {},
quantity: {},
shipping: {},
sku: {},
sort_order: {},
status: {},
stock_status_id: {},
subtract: {},
tax_class_id: {},
topleft_png: {},
topright_png: {},
upc: {},
viewed: {},
weight: {},
weight_class_id: {},
width: {}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

**Sample document**

```
  "_index": "clipboards",
            "_type": "products",
            "_id": "100",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "product": {
                  "product_id": "100",
                  "model": "9043",
                  "sku": "",
                  "upc": "",
                  "ean": "",
                  "jan": "",
                  "isbn": "",
                  "mpn": "",
                  "location": "",
                  "quantity": "67",
                  "stock_status_id": "8",
                  "image": "catalog/Clipboards/Clipboard_accessories/Bands/ISO-bands/iso-clipboard-bands-a29135.jpg",
                  "manufacturer_id": "13",
                  "shipping": "1",
                  "name": "9x4 truck"
                  "price": "4.9500",
                  "points": "360",
                  "tax_class_id": "9",
                  "date_available": "2013-09-08",
                  "weight": "0.05000000",
                  "weight_class_id": "5",
                  "length": "0.00000000",
                  "width": "0.00000000",
                  "height": "0.00000000",
                  "length_class_id": "3",
                  "subtract": "1",
                  "minimum": "1",
                  "sort_order": "1",
                  "status": "1",
                  "viewed": "585",
                  "date_added": "2015-04-07 02:04:21",
                  "date_modified": "2015-11-25 12:42:17",
                  "topleft_png": "",
                  "options": [
                     {
                        "product_option_value_id": "31",
                        "product_option_id": "232",
                        "product_id": "100",
                        "option_id": "17",
                        "option_value_id": "64",
                        "quantity": "100",
                        "subtract": "1",
                        "price": "0.0000",
                        "price_prefix": "+",
                        "points": "0",
                        "points_prefix": "+",
                        "weight": "0.00000000",
                        "weight_prefix": "+",
                        "option_name": "Black",

                        "main_option_heading_sort_order": "1",
                        "main_option_heading": "ISO Band Color"
                     },
                     {
                        "product_option_value_id": "32",
                        "product_option_id": "232",
                        "product_id": "100",
                        "option_id": "17",
                        "option_value_id": "65",
                        "quantity": "100",
                        "subtract": "1",
                        "price": "0.0000",
                        "price_prefix": "+",
                        "points": "0",
                        "points_prefix": "+",
                        "weight": "0.00000000",
                        "weight_prefix": "+",
                        "option_name": "Pink",

                        "main_option_heading_sort_order": "2",
                        "main_option_heading": "ISO Band Color"
                     },
                     {
                        "product_option_value_id": "33",
                        "product_option_id": "232",
                        "product_id": "100",
                        "option_id": "17",
                        "option_value_id": "66",
                        "quantity": "100",
                        "subtract": "1",
                        "price": "0.0000",
                        "price_prefix": "+",
                        "points": "0",
                        "points_prefix": "+",
                        "weight": "0.00000000",
                        "weight_prefix": "+",
                        "option_name": "Clear",

                        "main_option_heading_sort_order": "3",
                        "main_option_heading": "ISO Band Color"
                     }
                  ],
                  "product_gallery": []
               }
            }
         }
```

Comment: also mapping does not seem right, could you run curl -XGET `'localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_mapping'` and post the output of that?

Comment: It would help if you state your requirements more clearly, what documents should match for `9 x12`?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by what document? I need to search it on name field and on product type!

Comment: what I meant was what should match when your query is `9x 12`? every possible combination of `9 x12` like `9 x 12`, `9x 12` and `9 x 12` etc? could you share one sample document from index?

Comment: exactly thats what I am looking for. it should match all the combination of 9 X 12 . I will add sample document to the question

Comment: where is the `name` field? in which field you have stored ` 9 x 4 trucker`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99447/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-autolycus).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just starting with ES, one of the most important thing to understand is how [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis.html) works in ES. [This](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up) is a good starting point.

You are using `whitespace tokenizer` with `lowercase filter`, so when you index *9 X 12*, three tokens are stored in [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) namely *9*, *x* and *12*. When you index *9x12* only one token is generated i.e *9x12* itself. Now when you search *9 x12*, ES searches for either *9* **or** *x12* and hence it is not able to find the document indexed as *9x12*

**EDIT**

From your requirements I created following index

```
POST prod_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
         "vehicle_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "vehicle_extractor"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "vehicle_extractor": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(?i)(\\d+)\\s*x\\s*(\\d+)",
          "replacement": "$1x$2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "vehicle_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using [pattern_replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html), its job is to combine strings of the form *digit x digit* to single token e.g *9x 12*, *9 x 12* and *9 x12* will become *9x12*. You can use [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html?q=analyze) to see how `vehicle_ analyzer` is working.

Now your query will work fine. `9 x12` will return all possible combo, you will get `9x12 truck`, `9 x 12 car` etc. Now if you want to search for `9 x12 truck` use `match_phrase` instead of `match`.

Does this help?

Comment: hi Thanks. I tried it but unfortunately it did not return any results for 9 x 12 or 9x12 or anything else. I am not getting anything back. Here is the query that I am using

Comment: {
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "9x12"
        }
    }
}

Comment: It worked for me, I tested it yesterday, you are using the same analyzer I wrote?

Comment: Look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/chintan-shah-25/33cf9641931beaaa8ce7). pls double check your mapping. You have to delete existing index, create new one and reindex all your docs

Comment: Hi thanks...for some reason I am getting results(incorrect) back from your products data which is improvement from mine data where I get nothing back. Your results are showing 9x11 instead of all 9 x12. here is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/96c57ee77304d0dbe4f9

Comment: I have added comments to gist. have a look at it. I am almost certain that analyzer is not getting applied to name field